# How to use additional field in user details vs @PostAuthorize in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I what to add new field "tenant" to user details to use it in @PostAuthorize.
On @PostAuthorize("returnObject == principal.tenant") i receive error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/sectst] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'returnObject == principal.tenant'] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 26): Field or property 'tenant' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:216)
```

Can't understand why it looks through default User class instead of my custom ExtendedUser

My custom User Class

```
    public class ExtendedUser extends User {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3149421282945554897L;
    private final String tenant;

    public ExtendedUser(String username, String password,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, String tenant) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
        this.tenant = tenant;

    }

    public ExtendedUser(String username, String password, boolean enabled,
            boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired,
            boolean accountNonLocked,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, String tenant) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        this.tenant = tenant;
    }

    public String getTenant() {
        return tenant;
    }
}
```

And Custom UserDetails

```
    public class ExtendedJdbcUserDetailsService extends JdbcDaoImpl {

    private String extendedUsersByUsernameQuery;

    public String getExtendedUsersByUsernameQuery() {
        return extendedUsersByUsernameQuery;
    }

    public void setExtendedUsersByUsernameQuery(String extendedUsersByUsernameQuery) {
        this.extendedUsersByUsernameQuery = extendedUsersByUsernameQuery;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<UserDetails> loadUsersByUsername(String username) {
        return getJdbcTemplate().query(extendedUsersByUsernameQuery, new String[] {username}, new RowMapper<UserDetails>() {
            public UserDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                String username = rs.getString(1);
                String password = rs.getString(2);
                String tenant = rs.getString(3);
                boolean enabled = rs.getBoolean(4);
                return new ExtendedUser(username, password, enabled, true, true, true, AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES, tenant);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Edit:**
I have overrided createUserDetails method and it solved the problem

```
@Override
    protected UserDetails createUserDetails(String username, UserDetails userFromUserQuery,
            List<GrantedAuthority> combinedAuthorities) {
        String returnUsername = userFromUserQuery.getUsername();

        return new ExtendedUser(returnUsername, userFromUserQuery.getPassword(), userFromUserQuery.isEnabled(),
                true, true, true, combinedAuthorities, ((ExtendedUser) userFromUserQuery).getTenant());
    }
```

Comment: Add some logging to your `ExtendedJdbcUserDetailsService` and check if it is used.